# With AngularJS, how can I leverage ng-show against an array to find certain values?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-directive, meanjs

I have a model, `Program`, that looks something like this

```
var ProgramSchema = new Schema({
  permissions: [{
      user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      },
      roles: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: ['reader', 'editor', 'admin', 'requested']
          }]
      }
    }],
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['public', 'private'],
    default: 'public',
    required: 'Type cannot be blank'
  }
});
```

As display a list of `programs` on a page, I want to show an icon if the currently authenticated user `$scope.authentication.user` is in the `program.permissions.user` and with a role of reader, editor, or admin.
I was thinking of an `ng-show` but since `programs.permissions` is an array, I couldn't make it work. 
Any help would be great! thanks!

sample `program` data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55ab4acd24640cd55097c356"),
    "permissions" : [ 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("55a897dfad783baa677e1326"),
            "roles" : [ 
                "reader"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("5563f65a84426d913ae8334e"),
            "roles" : [ 
                "editor"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

---

Thru some help, here is what I ended up doing

I called a function in my ng-show

```
ng-show="userFollowedProgram(program)"
```

In my controller

```
$scope.userFollowedProgram = function(program) {
  //loop thru permissions and see if user is in there.
  for (var i = 0; i < program.permissions.length; i++) {
    if (program.permissions[i].user === $scope.authentication.user._id) {
      //loop thru roles and see if user is following.
      if (program.permissions[i].roles.indexOf('admin') > -1 ||
          program.permissions[i].roles.indexOf('editor') > -1 ||
          program.permissions[i].roles.indexOf('reader') > -1) {
          return true
        }
    }
  }
  return false;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not be the prettiest, you can explicitly check for your values with the `||` logical operator on your `ng-show` using [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp). I've mocked a simple example, using a `<span>` as an "icon" - but you can certainly work the idea into your working copy from here. Observe the following...

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
    <span class="ico" 
          ng-show="user.roles.indexOf('reader') > -1 || user.roles.indexOf('editor') > -1 || user.roles.indexOf('admin') >-1">icon
    </span>
</li>
```

---

```
$scope.users = [{
        id: 1, name: 'bob', roles: ['reader', 'editor', 'admin']
    },{
        id: 2, name: 'jane', roles: ['reader']
    },{
        id: 3, name: 'chris', roles: ['editor']
    },{
        id: 4, name: 'susy', roles: ['requested'] // sorry susy
}];
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/x4yu7gb6/) - simple demo

---

Another interesting way you can accomplish could include testing for their role via regex and return a truthy value. Could be more overhead than it's worth, but check it out if you wish...

```
<span class="ico" ng-show="isInRole(user)" >icon</span>
```

---

```
$scope.isInRole = function(user) {
    return /(reader|editor|admin)/.test(user.roles.join('|'));
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zx0nby7u/) - regex demo

Comment: Thanks for this @scniro. Unfortunately, it is a bit more complicated unless I am totally missing the point. In a `Program` doc, it contains an array of permissions, which consists of a reference to a `User` and an array of `roles` it has. I have updated the question to show sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.

I called a function in my `ng-show`

```
ng-show="userFollowedProgram(program)"
```

In my controller

```
$scope.userFollowedProgram = function(program) {
  for (var i = 0; i < program.permissions.length; i++) {
    if (program.permissions[i].user === $scope.authentication.user._id) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;

};
```

Comment: @scniro what do you think of this  implementation. I got the job done but it feels a bit brute force. thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't really see any roles in here. Were my examples not able to get you in the right direction? Sure it's a simplified demo - but I'd imagines it's pretty trivial to work around your syntax